# CakePHP loginAction not working

Tags: php, cakephp

**What I want:**
When a user is not logged in and tries to visit the site at any url they get redirected to /landing (which has a form on it that posts to /login)

**What is happening:**
When a user is not logged in and tries to visit the site at any url they get redirected to /login

In my AppController I have:

```
public $components = array(
        'Auth' => array(
            ...
            'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'twitter', 'action' => 'index'),
            'loginAction' => '/landing',
            'logoutRedirect' => '/landing',
            'unauthorizedRedirect' => '/landing',
            'authorize' => array('Actions' => array('actionPath' => 'controllers'))
        ));

        public function beforeFilter() {
            $this->Auth->allow('login', 'landing');
        }
```

I thought `'loginAction' => '/landing'` would have been the solution but it has not helped

Any ideas?

Comment: You only allow user visit 'login' page in beforeFilter , try to add 'landing' too

Comment: I already did, forgot to add it into the snippet. Updated now

Comment: Where do the routes for `/landing` and `/login` point respectively?

Comment: /landing is /pages/display/landing . /login is /users/login

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the controller?

```
'Auth' => array(
            'loginRedirect' => array(
                'controller' => 'items',
                'action' => 'index'
            ),
            'logoutRedirect' => array(
                'controller' => 'users',
                'action' => 'login'
            ),
            'authenticate' => array(
                'Form' => array(
                    'passwordHasher' => 'Blowfish'
                )
            )
        )
```

Comment: /login and /landing are routed to their respective controllers and actions. Using the array form still does not work anyway

Answer (score 0):

From your snippet it looks like you're putting `$this->Auth->allow()` rules in the `beforeFilter()` method of `AppController`:

```
public function beforeFilter() {
    $this->Auth->allow('login', 'landing');
}
```

The problem is that since your `/landing` route points to your `pages` controller and `/login` to your `users` controller, unless your controllers' `beforeFilter()` method call their parent's method like this:

```
public function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();
}
```

these rules won't ever take action. And if you add this code above, you're actually allowing both `landing` and `login` methods in both controllers (if they exist).

The way it is now, the parent is (apparently) never called, and so when you visit a url like `/bogus`, you get redirected to `/landing` as you've set in `AuthComponent`'s `loginAction`. But since this is never explicitely allowed in `pages` controller `beforeFilter()`, you get redirected again to `/login`. The whole process looks like you are *always* redirected to `/login` no matter what url you visit.

Keep in mind, that as you have it, the `allow()` rule for `login` is neither executed. You're able to visit `/login` though, because cake automatically allows it (or else you would end up in an endless loop).

So first remove the `landing` rule from `allow()`. You don't need it.

Then move the `beforeFilter()` code to the `pages` controller. Change `landing` to `display` as the method that is called is `display` inside that controller, being passed the argument `landing`. There's no `landing` method there (I assume - and if there is, the route is pointing to `pages`' `display` so it wouldn't have any effect)!

This last change will make `display` action allowed for any given page passed as argument (like `landing`, `home`, `eula` or whatever else you might be having). If you don't want that you should add a check either in the `beforeFilter()` or the `display()` and only allow the request to continue if the argument is `landing`.